# Export to excel in xul

Tags: javascript, excel, tree, xul, export-to-excel

So I have my function in js and xul that is creating export file in ods or xlsx. Exporting in ods is working just fine, but the problem is when I try to export in excel file format. The plan was to create xml file content.xml that will be generated by treeToXLSX.xsl. Content.xml is generated and when i extract export.xlsx it is in there, but the xlsx is empty. These are my files

TREE.JS

```
if(exportType == 'excel'){
    xslFile = "treeToXLSX.xsl";
    tempExportFile = "export.xlsx.tmp";
    exportTemplate = "template.xlsx";
    exportedFileName = "export.xlsx";
}else{
    xslFile = "treeToODS.xsl";
    tempExportFile = "export.ods.tmp";
    exportTemplate = "template.ods";
    exportedFileName = "export.ods";
}

var newdoc = this.prep(xslFile);

// save newdoc as /tmp/content.xml
var foStream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1"]
    .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFileOutputStream);

var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"]
    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIProperties)
    .get("TmpD", Components.interfaces.nsIFile);
file.append("content.xml");

var file2 = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"]
    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIProperties)
    .get("TmpD", Components.interfaces.nsIFile);
file2.append(tempExportFile);
file2.createUnique(Components.interfaces.nsIFile.NORMAL_FILE_TYPE, 0666);
file2.remove(false);

var serializer = new XMLSerializer();

// use 0x02 | 0x10 to open file for appending.
foStream.init(file, 0x02 | 0x08 | 0x20, -1, 0); // write,
                                                    // create,
                                                    // truncate
// In a c file operation, we have no need to set file mode with or
// operation, directly using "r" or "w" usually.
serializer.serializeToStream(newdoc, foStream, "UTF-8");
foStream.close();

var template = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"]
    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIProperties)
    .get("AChrom", Components.interfaces.nsIFile);

template.append("<path>");
template.append("<to_file>");
template.append(exportTemplate);

// copy export.ods template file into temp, BLOCKING OPERATION
template.copyTo(file2.parent, file2.leafName);

var zipWriter = Components.Constructor("@mozilla.org/zipwriter;1", "nsIZipWriter");
var zipW = new zipWriter();

zipW.open(file2, 0x04);
zipW.addEntryFile(file.leafName, Components.interfaces.nsIZipWriter.COMPRESSION_DEFAULT, file, false);
zipW.close();

var homedir = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"]
    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIProperties)
    .get("Home", Components.interfaces.nsIFile);

// open a save as dialog box
var fp = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/filepicker;1"]
    .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFilePicker);

fp.init(window, "Export as", Components.interfaces.nsIFilePicker.modeSave);
fp.appendFilters(Components.interfaces.nsIFilePicker.filterAll | Components.interfaces.nsIFilePicker.filterText);
fp.displayDirectory = homedir;
fp.defaultString = exportedFileName;

var rv = fp.show();

if (rv == Components.interfaces.nsIFilePicker.returnOK || rv == Components.interfaces.nsIFilePicker.returnReplace) {
    file2.moveTo(fp.file.parent, fp.file.leafName);
} else {
    file2.remove(false);
}
```

TREETOXLSX.XSL

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>

<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>  
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:user="urn:my-scripts"
  xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
  xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
  xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:param name="title" />
  <xsl:param name="skipfields" />
  <xsl:param name="decimals" />
  <xsl:param name="numerics" />

   <xsl:template match="*">
     <Workbook>
    <Worksheet ss:Name="Test"> 
      <Table x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1">
        <Row ss:Height="12.1032">
        <xsl:for-each select="child::*[1]/@*">
          <xsl:if test="not(contains($skipfields, concat('|', name(), '|')))">
             <Cell>
            <Data ss:Type="String">
              <xsl:value-of select="translate(name(), '_', '')"/>
            </Data>
             </Cell>
              </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
         </Row>
         <xsl:for-each select="./*">
           <Row>
          <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:if test="not(contains($skipfields, concat('|', name(), '|')))">
              <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($decimals, concat('|', name(), '|'))">
              <Cell>
                <Data ss:Type="Number">
                  <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </Data>
              </Cell>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains($numerics, concat('|', name(), '|'))">
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="Number">
                 <xsl:value-of select="." />
               </Data>
            </Cell>
             </xsl:when>
             <xsl:otherwise>
            <Cell>
               <Data ss:Type="String">
                  <xsl:value-of select="." />
               </Data>
            </Cell>
            </xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </Row>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </Table>
</Worksheet>
```

CONTENT.XML

```
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
  <Worksheet xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" ss:Name="Test">
    <Table xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1">
      <Row ss:Height="12.1032">
       <Cell>
         <Data ss:Type="String">ID</Data>
       </Cell>
       <Cell>
         <Data ss:Type="String">Name</Data>
       </Cell>
       <Cell>
         <Data ss:Type="String">Type</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell>
         <Data ss:Type="String">Group</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell>
         <Data ss:Type="String">Totaltickets</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell>
         <Data ss:Type="String">Wontickets</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell>
         <Data ss:Type="String">Moneyin</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell>
         <Data ss:Type="String">Moneyout</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell>
         <Data ss:Type="String">Percentage</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell>
         <Data ss:Type="String">Average</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell>
         <Data ss:Type="String">Moneyleft</Data>
      </Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <Cell>
         <Data ss:Type="Number">999</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell>
         <Data ss:Type="String">test</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell>
         <Data ss:Type="String"/>
      </Cell>
      <Cell>
         <Data ss:Type="String">a</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell>
         <Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell>
         <Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell>
         <Data ss:Type="Number">0,00</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell>
         <Data ss:Type="Number">0,00</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell>
         <Data ss:Type="Number">0</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell>
         <Data ss:Type="Number">0,00</Data>
      </Cell>
      <Cell>
         <Data ss:Type="Number">0,00</Data>
      </Cell>
   </Row>
</Table>
```

The strange thing is that exporting to ods file works perfectly, so I'm realy stuck. I have all needed files in my directory, `treeToXLSX.xsl` that generates `content.xml` and `template.xlsx`.

Comment: You forgot to specify what's wrong with this `content.xml` file.

Comment: @WladimirPalant nothing is wrong with content.xml file. When i try to open it as xml file from my temp folder in excel it opens without any problem. The real problem is copying content from xml file to xlsx file. When i open export.xlsx file it's always empty.

Comment: Try opening the generated file with text editor, to manually check if there is some syntax error, missing xml tags, tags not closed properly etc type issues.

Comment: @anishsane generated file is content.xml and it doesn't look like it has any syntax errors and all tags are closed.

Answer (score 2):

There are missing closing tags in your `TreeToXLSX.xsl` and `content.xml` files, but that may be a copy-paste mistake when you created the question.

Also, in your XSL file, try changing `<xsl:template match="*">` to `<xsl:template match="/Workbook">` to match the root element of the XML input.

Finally, the file you are creating here looks like the Excel [XML Spreadsheet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#XML_Spreadsheet) format, not the Office Open XML format.  XML Spreadsheet files should have the file extension ".xml" or ".xls", not ".xslx".

Comment: Thank you for your replay, unfortunately none of your suggestion solved the problem.